# Make coverage only count successful tests and ignore xfailing tests

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I have a number of projects where I use the `pytest.mark.xfail` marker to mark tests that fail but *shouldn't* fail so that a failing test case can be added before the issue is fixed. I do not want to *skip* these tests, because if something I does causes them to start passing, I want to be informed of that so that I can remove the `xfail` marker to avoid regressions.

The problem is that because `xfail` tests actually run until they fail, any lines hit leading up to the failure are counted as "covered", *even if they are part of no passing test*, which gives me misleading metrics about how much of my code is actually tested as working. A minimal example of this is:

**pkg.py**

```
def f(fail):
    if fail:
        print("This line should not be covered")
        return "wrong answer"

    return "right answer"
```

**test_pkg.py**

```
import pytest
from pkg import f

def test_success():
    assert f(fail=False) == "right answer"

@pytest.mark.xfail
def test_failure():
    assert f(fail=True) == "right answer"
```

Running `python -m pytest --cov=pkg`, I get:

```
platform linux -- Python 3.7.1, pytest-3.10.0, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /tmp/cov, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.6.0
collected 2 items

tests/test_pkg.py .x                                            [100%]

----------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.7.1-final-0 -----------
Name     Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------
pkg.py       5      0   100%
```

As you can see, all five lines are covered, but lines 3 and 4 are only hit during the `xfail` test.

The way I handle this now is to set up `tox` to run something like `pytest -m "not xfail" --cov && pytest -m xfail`, but in addition to being a bit cumbersome, that is only filtering out things with the `xfail` mark, which means that *conditional* xfails also get filtered out, regardless of whether or not the condition is met.

Is there any way to have `coverage` or `pytest` not count coverage from failing tests? Alternatively, I would be OK with a mechanism to ignore coverage from `xfail` tests that only ignores conditional `xfail` tests if the condition is met.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea! In the coverage 5.0 alpha, we can track which tests covered which lines.  If we get to the point of a pytest plugin to help with that, perhaps it could disable measurement around xfail tests.

Comment: Would you mind writing this up as an issue on the coverage.py repo? https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy

Comment: @NedBatchelder Will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the `pytest-cov` plugin, take advantage of its [`no_cover`](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markers-fixtures.html#no-cover) marker. When annotated with `pytest.mark.no_cover`, the code coverage will be turned off for the test. The only thing left to implement is applying `no_cover` marker to all tests marked with `pytest.mark.xfail`. In your `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest

def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        if item.get_closest_marker('xfail'):
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.no_cover)
```

Running your example will now yield:

```
$ pytest --cov=pkg -v
=================================== test session starts ===================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.1, pytest-3.9.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/hoefling/projects/private/stackoverflow, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.6.0
collected 2 items

test_pkg.py::test_success PASSED                                                     [ 50%]
test_pkg.py::test_failure xfail                                                      [100%]

---------- coverage: platform darwin, python 3.7.1-final-0 -----------
Name     Stmts   Miss  Cover
----------------------------
pkg.py       5      2    60%


=========================== 1 passed, 1 xfailed in 0.04 seconds ===========================
```

#### Edit: dealing with condition in the `xfail` marker

The marker arguments can be accessed via `marker.args` and `marker.kwargs`, so if you e.g. have a marker

```
@pytest.mark.xfail(sys.platform == 'win32', reason='This fails on Windows')
```

access the arguments with

```
marker = item.get_closest_marker('xfail')
condition = marker.args[0]
reason = marker.kwargs['reason']
```

To consider the condition flag, the hook from above can be modified as follows:

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    for item in items:
        marker = item.get_closest_marker('xfail')
        if marker and (not marker.args or marker.args[0]):
            item.add_marker(pytest.mark.no_cover)
```

Comment: This seems like it's half the solution; conditionally xfailing tests also need to have coverage turned off only if the failure condition is met. I think this probably solves the hardest part of the problem, though.

Comment: oh, you want coverage to be turned off for tests with an `xfail` _result_ (but e.g. left turned on for tests with an `xpass` result)? Kind of post-processing of coverage results _after_ the test has finished?

Comment: No, `xfail` takes a boolean, so you can express things like "this fails on Windows". I always run with `xfail` defaulting to strict, but in my experience, tests get the `xfail` *mark* regardless of whether the bool is true.

Comment: I see what you mean; the condition flag is the first attribute in the marker args, so it's not hard to include that into consideration. I have updated the answer with an example.

Comment: shouldn't your example show coverage @100% to prove this is working?

Comment: @Tony no, why should it do that?

Comment: This will still fail --cov-fail-under=61 when i'd expect it not to be included.

Comment: If you want full coverage, just don't do any changes - the code in the question has full coverage already. The question was about running all tests, but having the coverage report from the run without xfailing tests: recall _The way I handle this now is to set up tox to run something like `pytest -m "not xfail" --cov && pytest -m xfail`_. What is your use case then?